# Sencha Touch PullRefresh event

Tags: sencha-touch

Using the latest version of Sencha Touch 2.3.1a, what event can I use to fire after I pull down the refresh and it goes back up.  Ive tried all of them and nothing:

```
{
xtype: 'list',
itemId: 'passDownList',
store: 'PassDownEntrysStore',
plugins: 
[
    {
        xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
        autoPaging: true
    },
    {
        xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
        pullText: 'Pull down to refresh',

        listeners:
        {


        }
    }
],
```

I left them out of the listeners cause they didnt do anything.  But ive tried the events on the PullRefresh list of events like topchange, bottomchanged, etc.

**Update: 6/20/2014**

The way i got it to work was to override the fetchLatest() method.  I know its not the most elegant but it works  wish there was an actual event for it though.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can't you just use the `refreshFn`?

Comment: Unfortunately ver 2.3.1a doesnt have that event anymore.  What i ended up doing is overridding fetchLatest() function and works.  Im just changing a badge text on a button after the refresh is done.